# Video playback (HTML5 VideoElement) Apple Vision Pro Simulator in VR mode not playing

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, webvr, webxr, visionos

I'm working on a webVR video player. The HTML video element is loaded and playing in regular 3D view using ThreeJS and a VideoTexture mapped to a plane. It works on Chrome and Safari.

Now I've added webVR mode by adding the button and starting the VR session. It works fine on Chrome and using the WebXR plugin for chrome. With 'it works fine' I mean the video keeps playing when I enter VR mode and exit VR and enter again. All good.

On Apple Vision Pro Simulator, it works fine in Safari in 3D mode. However, as soon as I'm entering VR mode (when the confirmation popup comes up) the video stops updating on the mapped texture. It is still continuing in terms of progressing along the timeline but sound and update of the video texture stop in VR mode. Once I close VR mode again the video is playing again continuing at the time that has passed between opening VR and now.
I hope this makes sense. It is part of a bigger project but I'm working on sharing an example.

A demo video is here: https://youtu.be/ZNnadIutLsc

Answer (score 0):

I can make a 3D environment in the ThreeJS scene, configure xr controllers, and, when I enter VR mode on the Apple Vision Pro Simulator, I can still navigate around the scene.
To add more details: with a video player in the scene, playback works fine while in the 2D window mode; but as soon as I enter VR mode the window freezes on the last rendered frame (it does not go all dark). If I rotate or navigate around, in VR mode, the rendered image is still frozen, but if I exit VR mode, the navigation applied while in VR has been executed and rendering (and playback) starts working again.